# Multiple inhetitance and protected variable in java()

Tags: java, interface, multiple-inheritance

As we know in Java we can't have multiple inheritance and protected variable in interface, so how can I implement this code?

**Bar.java**

```
public class Bar {
    protected int  a = 0;
    public void increaseA() {
        a++;
    }
    public void printA() {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

**Foo.java**

```
public class Foo extends Bar, FooBar {
    @Override
    public void printClassName() {
        printClassName();
        System.out.println("Foo");
    }
}
```

**FooBar.java**

```
public class FooBar {
    void printClassName(){
        System.out.println("FooBar");
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        FooBar fooBar = foo;
        foo.printClassName();
        Bar bar = foo;
        bar.increaseA();
        bar.printA();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use an `interface` with a `default` method in Java 8.

Comment: @PeterLawrey What should i do with " Protected in a  = 0"

Comment: Leave `a` where it is in `Bar`

Comment: @PeterLawrey please Look at my code(answer) I have implement it but not exactly as you say

Comment: To make it work, you have to change it. I suggest you use an interface for `FooBar` if you want it to work.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have made it interface before you say   but thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
abstract class Bar {
    protected  int  a = 0;
    public  void increaseA() {
        a++;
    }
    public void printA() {
        System.out.println(a);
    }


}

interface FooBar {
    default void printClassName(){
        System.out.println("FooBar");
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar implements FooBar {
    @Override
    public void printClassName() {
        FooBar.super.printClassName();
        System.out.println("Foo");
    }
}



public class Q4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        FooBar fooBar = foo;
        foo.printClassName();
        Bar bar = foo;
        bar.increaseA();
        bar.printA();
    }
}
```

And so the output is

> FooBar
>
> Foo
>
> 1

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose try to use composition(here we got Mediator pattern)

```
  public interface BarInterface {
    void increaseA();

    void printA();
  }

  public interface FooBarInterface {
    void printClassName();
  }

  public class FooBar implements FooBarInterface {
    @Override
    public void printClassName() {
      System.out.println("FooBar");
    }
  }

  public class Bar implements BarInterface {
    protected int a = 0;

    public void increaseA() {
      a++;
    }

    public void printA() {
      System.out.println(a);
    }
  }

  public class Foo implements BarInterface, FooBarInterface {

    private final BarInterface bar;
    private final FooBarInterface fooBar;

    public Foo(Bar bar, FooBar fooBar) {
      this.bar = bar;
      this.fooBar = fooBar;
    }

    @Override
    public void printClassName() {
      fooBar.printClassName();
    }

    @Override
    public void increaseA() {
      bar.increaseA();
    }

    @Override
    public void printA() {
      bar.printA();
    }
  }
```